# Полноценный аналог .addEventListener() в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть ли в реакт аналог .addEventListener()?
Задача следующая: есть форма, в форме - инпуты. Есть див с содержимым, это рендерит реакт (reactdiv в примере). Здесь должны отобразиться результаты того или иного события в форме. Допустим, по клику на кнопку вывести в reactdiv "привет, мир!", разметка:

```
<form ...>
         ... 
    <input type="submit" ...>
</form>

<div id="reactdiv"></div>
```

*Пояснение: методы реакта записать прямо в тег не подойдут, так как форма не рендерится реактом, а на инпуты нужно динамически вешать события.*

Если использовать стандартный метод, то он отрабатывает, надпись появляется - и тут же исчезает из reactdiv.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли аналоги в реакте или для решения может в какую-то другую сторону нужно смотреть? Что можно почитать по этому поводу?

Comment: А почему нельзя сделать форму с помощью реакта?

Comment: Если на некоторых компонентах нужно менять событие или дополнительно добавить, то упрусь в тот же вопрос - аналог eventlistener'ов.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно, то вешайте обработчик через addEventListener в componentDidMount(){}
Хотя все события React типа "onClick" отрабатываются по факту внутри движка через addEventListener.

Comment: События действительно срабатывают, но только если это не сам рендер, можно ли это как-то сделать?